# Android change activity with animation from touch point

Tags: android, animation

I need some help in animationm, my requirement is that I need to start new activity with animation like 
from touch point of user the part of screen that is above that row moves up and part of screen that is below that row moves down and new activity appears from bottom

something similar to iPhone iCal app when it changes from month view to week view

Comment: please clear your question. you mean on swipe your screen activity should change. and current activity go through top and new activity appears from bottom.

Comment: You will get your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116069/animated-screen-splitting-in-android). The extra work you have to do is get the coordinates of point user touched.