# Animate view breaking in half crookedly

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to make an animation with a layout which contains a background and some text (TextViews) inside it. The animation should make the whole layout crack in the middle and then move slightly like a paper tearing. So not along a straight line but a random zig-zag pattern along the middle of the layout from top to bottom.

I've been trying to find something like this so can I get an idea how to do this but have not been able to so far. Does anyone know how something like this can be done on Android?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

You can try Brokenview Or ExplosionField.
Brokenview(https://github.com/zhanyongsheng/BrokenView).
ExplosionField(https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116393/3919009)? In the [blog](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/03/13/activity-split-animation) you have an explanation of how to achieve this behavior.

The idea behind is basically:

- Save your Activity's screen as a bitmap.
- Split it into two parts.
- Animate the bitmaps outwards.