# How to create a modal animation where sliding up for top half of the screen and sliding down for bottom half of the screen

Tags: swift, animation, modal-dialog, transition

I wanted to create a modal animation where top layout slide up and bottom layout slide down.

Similar to this image:

[image]

Note: The image was taken from [Vertical Screen Split Transitions (Animation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116069/vertical-screen-split-transitions-animation)

Answer (score 0):

Create an object and vends custom `present` animations:

```
class TheVendor: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return TheAnimator()
    }
}
```

Then create the animator:

```
class TheAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        // return a duration
    }
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // return the custom animation
    }
}
```

Then when you `present`, make the proper bindings:

```
presentedViewController.transitioningDelegate = TheVendor()
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Your image view what to split
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    // Start split animation
    self.splitAnimation(imgView: self.imgView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func splitAnimation(imgView: UIImageView){

    let topHalf = imgView.image?.topHalf

    let bottomHalf = imgView.image?.bottomHalf

    let imgViewTop = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgView.frame.size.width, height: imgView.frame.size.height/2.0))
    imgViewTop.image = topHalf

    let imgViewBottom = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: imgView.frame.size.height/2.0, width: imgView.frame.size.width, height: imgView.frame.size.height/2.0))
    imgViewBottom.image = bottomHalf

    imgView.addSubview(imgViewTop)
    imgView.addSubview(imgViewBottom)

    imgView.image = nil

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 1.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

        imgViewTop.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -imgView.frame.size.height/2.0, width: imgView.frame.size.width, height: imgView.frame.size.height/2.0)
        imgViewBottom.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: imgView.frame.size.height, width: imgView.frame.size.width, height: imgView.frame.size.height/2.0)

    }, completion: { (complete) in

        imgViewTop.removeFromSuperview()
        imgViewBottom.removeFromSuperview()
        imgView.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
}
```

Now add this extention to your class:

```
extension UIImage {

var topHalf: UIImage? {
    guard let cgImage = cgImage, let image = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height/2))) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: 1, orientation: imageOrientation)
}
var bottomHalf: UIImage? {
    guard let cgImage = cgImage, let image = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,  y: CGFloat(Int(size.height)-Int(size.height/2))), size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat(Int(size.height) - Int(size.height/2))))) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: image)
}
}
```

Manage time duration of the animation according to your self

Code Tested in Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1